# Boneh-Boyen like signature scheme

Tags: signature

[Full Boneh-Boyen signature scheme](http://crypto.stanford.edu/~dabo/abstracts/bbsigs.html) defines a pair of secret keys (SK) $a \in \mathbb{Z}_n$ and $b \in \mathbb{Z}_n$ and a pair of public keys (PK) $A = G^a \in \mathbb{G}$ and $B = G^b \in \mathbb{G}$. Can anybody point me out to some similar signature scheme where $SK \in \mathbb{Z}_n$ and $PK \in \mathbb{G}$?

Comment: [BLS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boneh–Lynn–Shacham) $\;$